# Why lambda function in list comprehension is slower than in map?

Tags: python, lambda

I made a test

```
%timeit list(map(lambda x:x,range(100000)))
%timeit [(lambda x:x)(i) for i in range(100000)]
```

gives

```
29 ms ± 4.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
51.2 ms ± 3.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Why in python lambda function is slower in list comprehension than in map?

Comment: Take note that the ``map`` call equivalent to your comprehension is actually ``list(map(lambda i: (lambda x:x)(i),range(100000)))``.

Answer (score 7):

Because in your first code snippet the `lambda` is created only once and executed 100000 times while on the second it is created and executed in every iteration.

To be honest I am surprised that the difference is not even bigger but your two timings should grow further apart the largest the length of the iterable is.

---

As a sidenote, notice that even if you change the `lambda` to a built-in function that does not have to be created first but rather only looked-up, you still get the same trend:

```
> py -m timeit "list(map(float, range(10000)))"
200 loops, best of 5: 1.78 msec per loop

> py -m timeit "[float(x) for x in range(10000)]"
100 loops, best of 5: 2.35 msec per loop
```

An improvement can be achieved by binding the function to a variable, but the `list(map())` scheme is still faster.

```
> py -m timeit "r=float;[r(x) for x in range(10000)]"
100 loops, best of 5: 1.93 msec per loop
```

As to *why* the binding to a local variable is faster, you can find more information [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-lookup-works.html).

Comment: Can you clarify the last paragraph? Using ``float`` is slower for exactly the same reason -- namely ``list(map())`` vs ``list-comprehension`` building the expression once versus every time. It's just much less of a difference because building a ``lambda`` is much more costly than looking up a ``builtin``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are absolutely right. I will edit it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Wow, that is unexpected. There are many places on the web advocating that list comprehension. So actually `map` has performance advanteges on functional mapping.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Hi, thank you for answering. BTW, I don't don't understand why  `r=float` would speed list comprehension a little(though still slower than map)? I think it still needs to look up. Why there should be a difference?

Comment: @user15964 because `r` is a local variable while `float` is a built in that can be overwritten. As a result, it takes more look-ups to find `float` than it takes to find `r` as the `locals` are searched first.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: A comprehension evaluates its entire expression every time. A `map` evaluates its expression once, and applies *the result* every time.

---

The expression fed to `map` and comprehensions are treated differently.
The important parts of what `map` and comprehensions are doing can be translated in the following way:

```
def map(func: 'callable', iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield func(item)

def comprehension(expr: 'code', iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield eval(expr)
```

The important difference is that `map` already receives a *function*, whereas `comprehension` receives an *expression*.

Now, `lambda x:x` is an expression that *evaluates to* a function.

```
>>> co = compile('lambda x: x', '<stackoverflow>', 'eval')
>>> co
<code object <module> at 0x105d1c810, file "<stackoverflow>", line 1>
>>> eval(co)
<function __main__.<lambda>(x)>
```

Notably, evaluating the expression to get the function is an action that takes time.

Since `map` and comprehensions expect different things, the `lambda` is passed to them differently. What the interpreter does can be expanded with explicit `eval`/`compile`:

```
>>> list(map(eval(compile('lambda x: x', '<stackoverflow>', 'eval')), range(10)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(comprehension(compile('(lambda x: x)(item)', '<stackoverflow>', 'eval'), range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The important difference should be clear now:

- For `map`, the expression is evaluated *once* before it is passed into `map`. For each item, `map` calls the resulting function.
- For `comprehension`, the expression is passed in unevaluated. For each item, `comprehension` *constructs the function*, then calls the resulting function.

---

It is important to note that `map` is not always faster than a comprehension. `map` benefits from creating/looking up a function once. However, function calls are expensive and a comprehension does not have to use a function.

In general, if the expression uses only names local to the comprehension, it is faster.

```
In [302]: %timeit list(map(lambda i:i,range(100000)))
     ...: %timeit [i for i in range(100000)]
8.86 ms ± 38.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.49 ms ± 35.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

If the expression itself *has* to dynamically do an expensive operation, `map` does not benefit.

```
In [302]: %timeit list(map(lambda i: (lambda x:x)(i),range(100000)))
     ...: %timeit [(lambda x:x)(i) for i in range(100000)]
19.7 ms ± 39.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
15.9 ms ± 43.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```